# Problems with Cabal when installing Agda

Tags: haskell, cabal, agda

Im trying to get Agda working following [this turtorial](http://williamdemeo.github.io/2014/02/27/learn-you-an-agda/). However when I type `cabal install agda` I get an error saying I have the wrong version of alex installed, I then use `cabal install alex` and after alex is installed I checks so that `alex -v` gives me the correct version which it does. I then try to run `cabal install agda` again but still it is complaining about wrong version of alex. I then put the exact path to alex on my path which is:

```
/Users/me/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/alex-3.1.4/bin
```

This works and fixes the problem for alex but now `cabal install agda` need the correct version of cpph.

So my questions is why do i need to put ever package directly on my systems path for cabal to find the latest version? Why can it not use the following path which has all the correct symlinks and is also on my systems path:

```
~/Library/Haskell/bin:
```

Answer (score 1):

The path `~/Library/Haskell/bin` should be the first one in the list of your paths.